# How to display every result of my for-loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, var

I'm trying to display each element of an array. My `for` loop is working but I can't display each result of my loop.

```js
function newCaseTemplate(filteredCase, filteredCaseTemplate, tagList) {
  var tagList = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < filteredCase.tags.length; i++) {
    tagList = filteredCase.tags[i].name + " | ";
  }

  var filteredCaseTemplate = `<span class="index-tagsCardCase">${tagList}</span>`

  $("#index-table").append(filteredCaseTemplate);
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: You seem to be overwriting the result of `tagList` within each iteration of the loop. Perhaps try: `tagList +=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting `tagList` on each iteration of the loop. Use `+=` to add to the previous string. I've also added a check not to add a pipe on the last tag.

```
for (var i = 0; i < filteredCase.tags.length; i++) {
    if(i === (filteredCase.length - 1)){
        tagList += filteredCase.tags[i].name;
    }else{
        tagList += filteredCase.tags[i].name + " | ";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log and see the output in your browser's developer tools (`Control-Alt-C` or `F12`) then select console tab.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < filteredCase.tags.length; i++) {
    console.log(filteredCase.tags[i].name);
    tagList += filteredCase.tags[i].name + " | ";
  }
```

Comment: I already did it and it shows me the 4 tags I want to display but when I use ${taglist} it shows only one tag

Comment: As in this code, and Rory's code, you need += operator to append to taglist.

Comment: I didn't see the "+=". It also works! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you overwrite `tagList` in every iteration of the `for` loop, so when the loop completes and you come to write to the DOM only the last value is shown.

An alternative approach to this would be to use `map()` to build an array which you can then `append()`. Try this:

```
function newCaseTemplate(filteredCase, filteredCaseTemplate, tagList) {
  var tagList = filteredCase.tags.map(function(tag) {
    return tag.name;
  });

  var filteredCaseTemplate = `<span class="index-tagsCardCase">${tagList.join(' | ')}</span>`;    
  $("#index-table").append(filteredCaseTemplate); 
}
```

Comment: This is an ES6 function - it'll need to be transpiled.

Comment: @ChrisWickham The OP is already using ES6 functionality, so I followed their precedent. It only needs transpiling if you need to support outdated browsers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good point - I didn't spot the string literal.